# How to write own Solr custom functional query to apply few selected field

Tags: spring-mvc, solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

Base on my requirement i have to write and apply function on few query selection fields. 
The below query is, i have to convert from mysql to solr. Is possible to apply custom function on Solr or any other way to achieve this in solr kindly share.

Mysql:

```
      select t.titleNo , 
              (select udConvertCurreny(t.currentPrice,T.currency, @preferredCurrency)
               from offerTitle 
                   where titleNo = T.titleNo 
                   and applyDate = now() ) as price
             from title as T;
```

Function:

```
 DELIMITER $$
   CREATE FUNCTION udfConvertCurrency ( currentPrice decimal, currency varchar, preferredCurrency varchar)
 RETURNS INT

 BEGIN

 IF currency != 'rs' THEN
 currentPrice = currentPrice / (select currencyRate from currency where currencytype =currency );


 RETURN currentPrice;

END; //

 DELIMITER ;
```